# Kendo grid angular sort column which has string values by number instead of string

Tags: sorting, kendo-ui

My Kendo grid has a column with values like 1, 10, 5, 11, 2. On clicking to sort by column header it returns 1,10,11,2,5. Even when I mention **filter="numeric"**, it doesnt help. How can I make angular understand that the column values are numeric and not string.

Comment: Set the data source model property type to `numeric`. Refer to https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schemamodel

Answer (score 0):

The Grid data must contain actual numbers (not string representations) in order to be sorted as expected:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/grid/sorting/basics/

Check the ID or Price columns - both contain actual numeric values.

If the data is coming from some remote service and contains strings, it can be mapped before passing it to the Grid, e.g.:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kedyru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Setting the filter to "numeric" would only affect the built-in filtering UI for the respective column.

You can also check the following KB article, it follows the same principle, but when handling dates:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/knowledge-base/grid-dates-treated-strings/